# Hyper-V 2008 R2 Install Question

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have 500GB HDD that I installed on the server. If I am going to load Hyper-V r2 on the bare system, do I set the partition to use all this space or is there a recommend smaller partition size I should set for Hyper-V to run within?

This is my first time loading Hyper-V bare to the system. I feel like I should be able to create a small partition of like 40GB for Hyper-V to run within. Then create a second larger partion to store my VM images.

Any thoughts or guidance on this?

Answer (score 2):

Our Hyper-V servers have a ~50GB C: drive. Hyper-V server takes about 10GB to install, Whatever your RAM size is for the swap file, and you need some breathing room, at least another 10GB.

This is assuming you are *using Hyper-V Server; not Windows Server + Hyper-V Role*. If this is just going to be a host, which **I highly recommend, use Hyper-V Server**. Installing even a core server plus the role will take more, and you'll be tempted to install other things on it, which will cause bloat...

Answer (score 0):

Yea we make 60-70GB C: partitions. You can always move swap file to D: (assuming these are all using the same disk set).  After patching with SP1, AV, backup, etc. the server OS tends to need lots of room compared to older Windows Server versions.